# Running cables from rear camera and parking sensors to car front in a Honda Fit 2015

Tags: honda, audio, parking, camera, fit

I'm planning to buy a rear camera and parking sensor kits to install myself in a Honda Fit 2015. While I have no trouble making the proper electrical connections, I have no previous experience running cables from the back to the front of the car, so I'd like to ask the more experienced folks the most adequate path or way to do it.

Since the system uses the rearview mirror to display the rear camera image, I suspect the cable should go under the top panel cover (that panel between the car ceiling and the car interior - I don't know the proper name for that in english) and down through one of the lateral front columns somewhere close to the car floor. Then I wonder the cable should go between the door rubber and the floor covering, but I'm not sure. Any tips?

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know the common way to run cabling from back to front is tucking it under the floor carpet, could be in the corner next to the door or in the middle. Then you could route it through the A-pillar, around the window and to the mirror.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing   -  I think your comment answers the question.  Could you post it as the answer?  Once it get's upvoted it will no longer be an unanswered question and good for the site.  :)   TY and Happy New Years!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common way to run cabling from the back of the car to the front is tucking it under the floor carpet near an edge, where passengers' feet don't frequently stomp.

For example you could route it along an edge next to the door, then through the B-pillar or A-pillar, around the windshield and to the rear view mirror.

Comment: In that particular case I ended up opening the plastic coverings which run along the floor close to the doors. The car´s original electrical cabling was there also, so I ended up almost following it all the way to the back, so your answer pretty much matched it. Thanks!